# creating directory in ftp server using ncftp command from ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, ftp, mkdir

How to create a directory in a specific path in Ftp server by using Ncftp command from Ubuntu terminal. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ncftp` you should have the ability to create directories at both a local and remote location:

1. **lmkdir** This command creates directories on the *local* host
2. **mkdir** This command creates directories on the *remote* host

Bear in mind that *you will need suitable permission on the remote host* to create any directories.

Below is an example on my own ftp server, I have obscured the username and password and added in a few arrows:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ ncftp ftp://username:password@andrews-corner.org/andrews-corner.org/test/
NcFTP 3.2.5 (Feb 02, 2011) by Mike Gleason (http://www.NcFTP.com/contact/).
Connecting to 208.113.217.97...
DreamHost FTP Server
Logging in...
User username logged in
Logged in to andrews-corner.org.                                
Current remote directory is /andrews-corner.org/test.
ncftp /andrews-corner.org/test > mkdir hello_sysadminboy                      <-----
ncftp /andrews-corner.org/test > dir                                          <-----
drwxr-xr-x   14709624 227249                Sep 12 12:50   hello_sysadminboy  <-----
ncftp /andrews-corner.org/test > quit
andrew@corinth:~$
```

You can see from the above that I have:

1. Successfully logged in and automatically changed to a test directory
2. Created the remote directory 'hello_sysadminboy'
3. Tested the directory with the `dir` command

If you wanted to *script* this sort of thing something like the following works well on my system:

```
#!/bin/sh

ncftp ftp://username:password@andrews-corner.org/andrews-corner.org/test/<<EOF
mkdir hello_sysadminboy
dir
EOF
```

Unfortunately the `mkdir -p` command does not work remotely to create nested directories and brace expansion is ignored...

Comment: i have tried it but it only provides login to ftp server directory is not created can you please provide the syntax?

Comment: @sysadminboy I have added an example from my own ftp server

Comment: it is for a script to automatcially create directory ..here you have done it manually

Comment: ncftp -u username -p password hostname:/path mkdir . is there something like this were directory is created in a single command?

Comment: @sysadminboy OK so I have added in a scripting example. Note that I have used a shorthand method for username and password. I am not aware of a method to accomplish this with a single command unfortunately...

Comment: @sysadminboy That is excellent news! And have a good day :)

Comment: is it possible to monitor a directory in ncftp server and if new files appear in that directory i need to copy it to my local system with ncftpget(something like watchfolder).

Comment: @sysadminboy I am not sure... This might be better as a new question?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/830570/automatic-directory-triggering-in-ftp . here is the qwestion please help me. Thanks

Comment: ssh pppp@192.168.0.542<<EOF inotifywait -m /tmp/sample/ -e create -e moved_to | while read path action file; do echo "new file found" #scp -r /tmp/sample/ gggg@192.168.0.562:/tmp/ done EOF ... by doing so i am able to get notification when a new file occurs but how to copy it to my system using ncftpget because every time a new file appears it has to be copied using ncftpget to my system ..is it possible.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/830570/automatic-directory-triggering-in-ftp ..here is that qwestion.  please help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-m` switch:

```
ncftpput -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> -P <PORT> -m noc.netmihan.com /REMOTE_DIR LOCAL_DIR/example.txt
```

Look at the [ncftp](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html) documentation for more info.