# Automatic directory triggering in ftp

Tags: 14.04, directory, ftp

I need to monitor a directory in FTP server from Ubuntu.If any new files appear in a specific directory in FTP server that files should be copied to my Ubuntu machine.I have ssh login to my FTP server. This automation should be done from my Ubuntu machine is it possible?

Comment: This looks more like a Cloud solution related question. Have you considered using PyDIO or OwnCloud? They are pretty easy to install and they do what you expect. It's like a Dropbox but under your computer's control. Just in case you wish to try a Cloud solution, just let me know in order to drop an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) can do this easily between two machines. If you have SSH access, you can use [port forwarding](http://Maybe%20worth%20giving%20syncthing%20a%20try%20-%20via%20ssh%20portforwarding) to connect the syncthing instances.

Comment: is it possible via shell script by setting watch folder? I dont need a third party application.

Comment: I assumed from the information you gave you can access via ftp and via ssh - but the server does not know the location of your Ubuntu machine and does not have access to it. Leaves you with polling - like setting up a 1 minute cron job that checks for new files and copies them. You where thinking in that direction? You cannot trigger towards an entity that you cannot reach.

Comment: is it possible to set a watch folder in ftp and if newl added files appear.  I need to copy it to my local machines using ncftpget. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, read the docs of the software you are using. If your server has that feature you can of course do that. I still assume that your ftp server cannot reach the Ubuntu machine - then you keep the problem how your watch event would tell the other end to start copying and what to copy. This is why I mentioned syncthing - it will watch any folder you point it to and sync its contents with the other end.

Comment: ssh pppp@192.168.0.542<<EOF    
  inotifywait -m /tmp/sample/ -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "new file found"
        #scp -r /tmp/sample/ gggg@192.168.0.562:/tmp/
    done
EOF

by doing so i am able to get notifications when a new file is found ...bt how to copy a file to my local system as soon as it is available in my ftp .because the file keep on changing and i can't give a specific file name to copy how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in [Automatic directory triggering in ftp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830570/automatic-directory-triggering-in-ftp/830572#comment1267134_830572) was almost there. Try

```
$ ssh "$SERVER" inotifywait -m /tmp/sample/ -e create -e moved_to \
  | while read d o f; do
      case "$o" in CREATE|MOVED_TO) 
        scp "$SERVER":/tmp/sample/"$f" /tmp/sample/;;
      esac
  done
```

However, if you want it to work with subdirs, you should probably just call rsync on each happening (rsync itself will figure out what file is new), and include -r to inotifywait, e.g.

```
$ ssh "$SERVER" inotifywait -r -m /tmp/sample/ -e create -e moved_to \
  | while read d o f; do
      case "$o" in CREATE|MOVED_TO) 
        rsync -avh "$SERVER":/tmp/sample /tmp/sample;;
      esac
  done
```

(If you want to do it with scp, you have to ensure local directories are created etc., which pretty much ends up re-implementing rsync.)

---

All that said, I recommend looking into Syncthing if you do this kind of thing a lot. It's quite resource-light.